# How to determine reason for ERROR 403: Forbidden?

Tags: web-scraping, wget

I'm making a script in order to scrap information from a bunch of websites.

On a site I can open with a web browser, I get an error message when I try to open it with wget : ERROR 403: Forbidden.

I have tried setting the same headers as my browser, but it didn't work. The robots.txt is granting robots access to the whole site, so I want to know if there is a way to learn the specific reason for which my robot is blocked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a tool like `Fiddler` and check if your request have any cookies being sent. If so, try making the request with these same cookies (I am not familiar with `wget`, no idea how would this be done/ if possible at all)

Comment: did you find any solution for this? Did `Fiddler` work for that?